# Dynamic changes in rails form (simpleform)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamic, simple-form

I'm trying to make a simple form with this general structure:

```
o accept  o decline
[submit]
```

when the radio button accept is checked and submit pressed, I want it to change the state of my model (called Offer here).
BUT when the button decline is checked, the form needs to change to something like this:

```
o accept  x decline
Please enter reason here: [text box]
[submit]
```

Having entered a (mandatory) reason for declining and pressing submit, will change the state of the model Offer too, but differently.

I'm currently having problems getting the form to display the way I want. I'm using SimpleForm and tried something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @offer do |f| %>
  <%= f.input accepts, as: :radio_buttons %>
  <%= f.input :r_comment, as: :text, :label => 'Please enter reason here:' , :input_html => { :rows => 2, } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This of course doesn't work, because there is no "accepts" method or variable defined for offers (and it shouldn't be!). As for dynamically showing the input text box, I don't even have the slightest clue.

I'd be glad for any help you might offer,

Lordylike

UPDATE: HTML generated by simple_form

```
<div class="control-group radio_buttons optional">
  <label class="radio_buttons optional control-label">Accept?</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="radio">
      <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="offer_accepts_decline" name="offer[accepts]" type="radio" value="Decline" />
      Decline
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="offer_accepts_accept" name="offer[accepts]" type="radio" value="Accept" />
      Accept
    </label>
  </div>
```

UPDATE: HTML generated for comment box

```
<div class="control-group text optional">
    <label class="text optional control-label" for="offer_r_comment">Reason for rejection:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea class="text optional" cols="40" id="offer_r_comment" name="offer[r_comment]" rows="2">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not a fan of formtastic or simple_form but looking at the documentation, you should be able to do the following

```
# offer.rb
attr_accessor :accepts

# view
<%= f.input :accepts, as: :radio_buttons, collection: ['Decline', 'Accept'] %>

# js which can be placed inline or in the assets. let's use coffee
# you should also limit the selector below to include the class or the id of the
# radio buttons.  I'm also not familiar with the html generated by simple form so
# the selectors to show and hide should also be changed.
$ ->
  $(':radio').change ->
    if $(this).prop('checked')
      if $(this).val() == 'Accept'
        $('#offer_r_comment').show()
      else
        $('#offer_r_comment').hide()
```

UPDATE: non coffee version. you can place this inside a script tag and just throw in the view.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked'))
      if ($(this).val() == 'Accept')
        $('#offer_r_comment').show();
      else
        $('#offer_r_comment').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first part solves my problems for the variable that doesn't exist. :)
For the 2nd part: I'm sorry I don't know what do do with it.
I guess you're trying to check the radio_button state with js. 
The code simple_form generates looks something like this:

Comment: <div class="control-group radio_buttons optional"><label class="radio_buttons optional control-label">Accept?</label><div class="controls"><label class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="offer_accepts_decline" name="offer[accepts]" type="radio" value="Decline" />Decline</label><label class="radio"><input class="radio_buttons optional" id="offer_accepts_accept" name="offer[accepts]" type="radio" value="Accept" />Accept</label></div>

Comment: Okay, sorry I think I didn't make myself clear: I have no idea how and where to put the js-code itself. I unfortunately haven't worked with js forever(just some little copy-paste snippets years ago).
I just put it inline with <script> tags, but nothing happens. So I guess I'm doing something wrong. I'm sorry for seeming willfully stupid...

Comment: no worries. i've updated the js version of the answer. next time you comment, please include the errors if there are any and not just say it's not working :)

Comment: I'd like to report an error, at least this way I knew what isn't working ;) Alas, as it it, the code just doesn't do anything at all. No matter what I select, the comment-box remains present :)
What other information could help you help me? :)

Comment: can you update your question with the html of the comment box?

Comment: ok updated my answer. this should at least work as long as the text field is wrapped in a div or has an id of offer_r_comment

Comment: Thank you very much. This does the trick :)
(If you have time to spare: the label of the comment box stays visible, how would I hide that too?)

Answer Accepted :)